# django ForeignKey with Choices - setting default value

Tags: python, django

I have a membership model that has three choices. I set the default of those choices in the membership model. However, I have a User model that has a ForeignKey relationship to the Membership model and when I try to set default='Personal' I get a ValueError.

ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Personal'.

**models.py**

```
MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES = (
    ('Enterprise', 'enterprise'),
    ('Premium', 'premium'),
    ('Personal', 'personal'),
)

class Membership(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    membership_type = models.CharField(
        choices=MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES,
        default='Personal',
        max_length=30)
    annual_monthly_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    monthly_monthly_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.membership_type

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False, verbose_name='first name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False, verbose_name='last name')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    user_team = models.ForeignKey('Team', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='userteam')
    team_leader = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    team_member = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_tasks = models.ManyToManyField('Task', through='UserTasks')

    # user types
    membership_type = models.ForeignKey(Membership, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default='Personal')

    # Abstract User fields
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I've tried clearing the migrations and deleting the database. The only way I've gotten this to work is by using:

```
on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True
```

inside the membership_type model field of CustomUser but I want the default for the user to be "Personal" when they sign up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error you are getting is because you have not defined a primary key in your `Membership` model. Therefore Django is doing this for you and using an `AutoField` which is a number.

Try changing your membership model to have `membership_type` as the primary key, i.e.

```
membership_type = models.CharField(
        primary_key=True,
        choices=MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES,
        default='Personal',
    max_length=30)
```

Comment: Looks like I was able to migrate the database but upon creating a superuser I get this error:
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Comment: return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Comment: I've tried creating and the only problems I encounter are to do with conficts between `AbstractUser` and `User`. I had no problems with the `membership_type` field ...

Comment: Created a brand new project and copied and pasted everything into it.  Before I was deleting migrations and pycaches as well as the database.  But apparently that only goes so far.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `membership_type` is a unique field, one possible method is:

```
#models.py

class Membership(models.Model):
    membership_type = models.CharField(
        choices=MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES,
        default='Personal',
        unique=True,
        max_length=30)
    ....

   
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
   ....
   membership_type = models.ForeignKey(Membership, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, to_field='membership_type', default='Personal')
```